# ignoring a class property in powershell c# cmdlet output

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am creating a powershell cmdlet in c# using System.Management.Automation dll and using WriteObject to display output.. is there any option like JsonIgnore attribute in NewtonSoft.Json which excludes the property from displaying in the shell

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: [You may want to check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878339(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: [`System.Management.Automation.HiddenAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.hiddenattribute.aspx)